# Can i use getDoctrine and getManager in an entity? I'm sorry but i don't understand how this works

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I want to use the getDoctrine and getManager functions in an entity. Is this possible? or is there any way arround this? I want to insert something in a database like this :

```
$history = new Policy();
        $history->setName($file1->getClientOriginalName());
        $history->setPolicyNumber($this->getPolicyNumber());
        $history->setOrderId($this->getOrderId());
        $history->setPath($this->getPathFile1());
        $history->setDocumentType($this->getDocument1Type());
        $history->setPrintAction($this);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($history);
        $em->flush();
```

Comment: I really don't understand what are you trying to do from the description above?

Comment: i want to insert in the Policy table a new object. In my PrintAction class, i am creating a new object "history" which is a Policy. Then, i insert in it some data and i want to put this data in the table.

Comment: The problem is, when i call getDoctrine it doesn't know who this function is. After some research i found out that this method is used for controllers, and i didn't find an equivalent method for entities

Comment: You are putting this inside your entity.php file? Why aren't you doing this inside a Controller action?

Comment: In symfony2 model object are not aware of datastorage they are in. That Means you can'y (and shouldn't) use getDoctrine in your entities. There are offcoures some ugly-hacky workaround, but I would not suggest any ot theme. Try doing it in some controler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Doctrine ORM, Entities have an unique role : data containers! 
According to Doctrine architecture, there is no reason to inject EntityManager inside.

If you need to do that, you're trying to put some code of the Business layer into layer. 
So try to move your code into a service, like a manager for your Entity or if you're lazy in a controller but it's a bit crapy.

Answer (score 1):

I would venture to first answer the question, and then give out advice.

If you look into source code of Doctrine2, you may to find this method in `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork`:

```
/**
 * @param ClassMetadata $class
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManagerAware|object
 */
private function newInstance($class)
{
    $entity = $class->newInstance();

    if ($entity instanceof \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManagerAware) {
        $entity->injectObjectManager($this->em, $class);
    }

    return $entity;
}
```

So... it means, if your entity implements `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManagerAware` you will have EntityManager inside Doctrine2 entity. That's it.

Now advice:

**IT'S REALLY BAD PRACTICE, AND NOT RECOMMENDED FOR USE**.

From PhpDoc of `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManagerAware` interface:

**Word of Warning: This is a very powerful hook to change how you can work with your domain models.
 Using this hook will break the Single Responsibility Principle inside your Domain Objects
 and increase the coupling of database and objects.**